# matlab vector with element condition and sum vector condition

Tags: matlab, vector, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a random vector who contains 5 elements (from 0 to 1) with 2 condition

1. All elements have to be smaller than 0.5
2. The sum of the vector needs to be 1

For instance this vector is not allowed  (because one element is bigger than 0.5)

```
[0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
```

For instance this vector is not allowed  (because the sum is bigger than 1)

```
[0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
```

For instance this vector is  allowed

```
[0.3, 0.25, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15]
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question is HOW to get the vector I am looking for, I dont know how to combine the 2 condition ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same using a value lesser than 0.5 to scale the random numbers and then normalizing the sum.

```
r = 0 + 0.45*rand(5,1);
s = sum(r);
norm_r = r/s
```

The range is always less than 0.5 and the sum is always equal to 1. I cannot tell upto what number can be multiplied to the rand variable but it must be less than 0.5 otherwise after normalization, one number might be greater than 0.5.